# Knockoutjs: how to set the asynchronous API query result as the observables

Tags: asynchronous, knockout.js

In my application, I am use the knockoutJS as the framework and want to query the API to get the data. The expect behavior is set the data in the KO's observables then the UI will be updated automatically. The HTML goes as below:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="options-box">
        <h1>Restaurant Finder</h1>
        <ul class="category-list" data-bind="foreach: categoryList">
          <li class="category-item" data-bind="text:$data, click: $parent.queryRestaurant"></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="location-list" data-bind="foreach: locationList">
         <li class="location-item" data-bind="text: title"></li> 
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
```

and the JS code goes as following:

```
  $(function(){
    console.log("debug inside the initmap")
    //The predefined restaurant categrory
    var restaurantCate = ["Sushi","Chinese Food","Coffee"];
    // the Location function for creating new location Knockout object 
    var Location = function(loc){
        return ko.observable(loc);
    };
    //the locatoinViewModel is the view model part for this application
    var locationViewModel =function() {
        var self = this;
        self.locationList = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.categoryList = ko.observableArray(restaurantCate);
        self.queryRestaurant = function(){
            console.log("hi");
            var foursquare_url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search";
            var Client_ID="xxx";
            var Client_Secret="xxx";
            foursquare_url += "?client_id=" + Client_ID + "&client_secret=" + Client_Secret + "&v=20130815" + "&ll=40.7413549,-73.9980244" + "&query=" + this;
            console.log(foursquare_url);
            queryFoursquare(foursquare_url);
        };
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new locationViewModel());
    //the queryFoursquare function 
    function queryFoursquare(queryurl){
        $.getJSON(queryurl,function(response){
            console.log(response["meta"]["code"]);
            var result = [];
            response["response"]["venues"].forEach(function(eachvenue){
                result.push({
                    title: eachvenue["name"],
                    location: {lat: eachvenue["location"]["lat"], lng:eachvenue["location"]["lng"]}
                });
            });
            locationViewModel.locationList(result);
        }).done(function(){
            console.log("done")
        }).fail(function(){
            alert("error happens during query data from Foursquare")
        });

    };    
  });
```

now the status is: the KO's viewmodel can work well and the API function can get the data as well. 
The problem is how to set the `result` array to the KO's observableArray `locationList`. How to deal with such async querying case?

**Edit:**
I forget to add the error message: `locationViewModel.locationList is not a function`.

**Edit II**

```
        var locationViewModel =function() {
        var self = this;
        self.locationList = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.categoryList = ko.observableArray(restaurantCate);
        self.queryRestaurant = function(){
            console.log("hi");
            var foursquare_url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search";
            var Client_ID="T3A2F5ZKOVEDWXZXLHFFNPU3DYTYIUZGPJELBWLJZVQFTALA";
            var Client_Secret="IM2R2QRHZR0CIOGCLYKGTOSBEPERM1JVA0X022CY3B4ZX41P";
            foursquare_url += "?client_id=" + Client_ID + "&client_secret=" + Client_Secret + "&v=20130815" + "&ll=40.7413549,-73.9980244" + "&query=" + this;
            console.log(foursquare_url);
            //queryFoursquare(foursquare_url);
            //Directly call the getJSON function inside viewmodel
            $.getJSON(foursquare_url,function(response){
                //console.log(response["meta"]["code"]);
                var result = [];
                response["response"]["venues"].forEach(function(eachvenue){
                    result.push({
                        title: eachvenue["name"],
                        location: {lat: eachvenue["location"]["lat"], lng:eachvenue["location"]["lng"]}
                    });
                });
                self.locationList(result)
            });
        };
    };
```

So after putting the AJAX call back into the viemmodel. Then by `self.locationList` the behavior goes as expected. 
If I want to separate the API call into a function, how to access the KO's observables?

Thank you

Comment: You're exposing your client id and secret to the world...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the updated post, it boils down to separating the `queryFoursquare` function from the viewModel. Instead of trying to access `locationList`inside the function, you can return `result` from the function and assign the return value to `locationList`like below -

```
//return the result array - 

return $.getJSON(foursquare_url, function(response) {
  //console.log(response["meta"]["code"]);
  var result = [];
  response["response"]["venues"].forEach(function(eachvenue) {
    result.push({
      title: eachvenue["name"],
      location: {
        lat: eachvenue["location"]["lat"],
        lng: eachvenue["location"]["lng"]
      }
    });
  });
  return result;
});

// Assign the return value to the locationList observable Array.
queryRestaurant().done(function(result) {
    //Do stuff with the response.
    self.locationList(dataPreparedFromResult);
    console.log(self.locationList());
});
```

This will make your code more re-usable.

**EDIT**

So, you will need to return a promise from your `queryRestaurant` function and in the `.done`handler, you need to push the data inside the observable array. Because, the assignment is done before the promise is returned, so you are getting `undefined` as the output.

Hope this finally helps...

Comment: Thx. But I think the key is how to access the `locationList` outside the viewmodel, based on the error message "locationViewModel.locationList is not a function". Please see my Edit in the original post.

Comment: That error puts us in a different situation now. I think now it depends on a lot of things, where is the queryFoursquare function kept, if in a spearate viewmodel, then the issue is to communicate between different view models/modules. What are you using to resolve the dependencies, etc..

Comment: THx. To simplify the problem, I only have one viewmodel. The code posted here is all stuff. regards

Comment: Hi, do you try your solution? In fact I tried this method of returning the result. But it didn't work me. It Seems that still the async issue, the `locationList` is set to empty...